# External monitor detected but shows no video output in Sway / Wayland

Tags: manjaro, display, multi-monitor, wayland, sway

I have an external monitor connected to a thunderbolt dock which I would like to utilize. For whatever reason, the monitor appears to be recognized by the system but fails to display anything.

- I can confirm that the cable and monitor are fine, as it works perfectly when booted into Windows
- The thunderbolt dock seems to not be the issue, as USB peripherals are working fine
- Running `swaymsg -t get_outputs` shows the built in monitor as `eDP-1` and the external monitor as `DP-2`. There is no indication here that the second monitor would not be working.
- Running `wdisplays` shows a preview of what the second display should look like, so evidently the system is rendering what is meant to be sent to the monitor
- When I reboot the machine, the tty output is mirrored onto the second monitor. So evidently it is recognized.
- There are no errors in `sway --debug`
- There are no entries in `dmesg` which appear related to the issue
- Running `lspci -k | grep -A 4 VGA` shows that the video driver is loaded

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G7 (rev 07)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 86f9
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

- I have set the environment variable `WLR_DRM_NO_MODIFIERS=1` as has been recommended to solve related issues
- I have attempted to install other versions of `wlroots` to no avail, though I honestly don't know whether this would be expected to fix the problem.
- While the refresh rate is very bad during normal use (hence why I am attempting this method), I can successfully use this monitor with an external Nvidia RTX 2060 GPU, connected via thunderbolt 3, with the the noveau driver.

I don't really have a sense of how to best approach troubleshooting this problem, so any advice would be appreciated! If there is any additional information that would be relevant, I am more than happy to provide it.

System information:

- OS: Manjaro 21.1.6 Pahvo
- WM: sway 1.6.1
- wlroots 0.14.1-2

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where my external displays were recognised and shown as usable in the settings, but whenever I tried to activate them and actually extend the displays, nothing happened and they remained black. I nice tooling from POP!_OS helped me out. I wrote a small post about it, hope it helps here too

[Extended Displays on Manjaro with AMD CPU and Nvidia GPU](https://gerstams.medium.com/extended-displays-on-manjaro-with-amd-cpu-and-nvidia-gpu-b214a4bbc5b7)